# C# asp.net get data from sql based on value from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with id column and button and if the user clicked the button he will be directed to another page with sql script to retrive data from database, and what I want to do is when the user is directed to the other page the displayed data is selected based on the id value on the gridview.

I tried to add button to catch the id value

here is my code for the button with id value in the gridview:

```
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Your field here">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="requests_page.aspx?id=<%#Eval("req_id") %>"><%#Eval("req_id") %></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

the problem is in the other page I don't know how to catch the id value to get the data based on it, here is my try:

```
"select * from requests where req_id = '"+ <%#Eval("req_id")%>'""
```

Comment: I think there’s more code needed here than what you’ve put into the question. Is this all you have?

Comment: the question is also a little misleading. Do you get the id on the 2nd page from your gridview or is the id not being passed? because your last line says the problem is on  the other page. meaning you do get the id on the second page but you wanna know how to catch the id?

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan  actually the issue not from the first page its from the second page because when I redirect to the next page I can see in the url the id value, but how I can get the id value in sql script to retrieve the data based on this id value

Comment: Now the issue is more clear i posted a solution for you. Tip! For next time only post your error and what you tried. The part of showing in gridview was working and making the question confusing.as the issue was for you how to read the request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Send A Query String And Get it Through request.params

```
<asp:HyperLink Text='<%# (Eval("Company"))%>' ID="HyperLink1" 
               Target="_blank" runat="server"  
                NavigateUrl="page2.aspx?variablename=value"/>
```

and get it through

```
"select * from requests where req_id = '"+request.params["variablename"]+"'"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the id from the request parameter and use it for your SQL you can get it by

```
private readonly int ObjectId = int.MinValue;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Request["id"] is the way to read the request parameter.
   //Below we just parse it to a int and if we succeed we read the data from sql.
   if(int.TryParse(Request["id"], out ObjectId))
   {
      ReadFromSql();
   }
}

protected void ReadFromSql(){
   // A check if the int is filled correctly incase you call from a other method.
   if(ObjectId != int.MinValue){
      // do your sql 
   } 
}
```